# What is the relation between syntax sugar, laziness and list elements accessed by index in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, language-design

Haskell lists are constructed by a sequence of calls to `cons`, after desugaring syntax:

```
Prelude> (:) 1 $ (:) 2 $ (:) 3 []
[1,2,3]
```

Are lists lazy due to them being such a sequence of function calls?
If this is true, how can the runtime access the values while calling the chain of functions?
Is the access by index also a syntax sugar?
How could we express it in other way, less sugared than this?:

```
Prelude> (!!) lst 1
2
```

The underlying question here might be:

**Are lists fundamental entities in Haskell, or they can be expressed as composition of more essential concepts?**

Are there possiblity to represent lists in the simplest lambda calculus?

I am trying to implement a language where the list is defined at the standard libray, not as a special entity directly hardwired in the parser/interpreter/runtime.

Comment: You can encode anything in the lambda calculus; that's pretty much the point of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lists in Haskell are special **in syntax**, but not fundamentally.

Fundamentally, Haskell list is defined like this:

```
data [] a = [] | (:) a ([] a)
```

Just another data type with two constructors, nothing to see here, move along.

The above is kind of a pseudocode though, because you can't actually define something like that yourself: neither `[]` nor `(:)` is a valid constructor name. A special exception is made for the built-in lists.

But you could define the equivalent, something like:

```
data MyList a = Nil | Cons a (MyList a)
```

And this would work *exactly* the same with regards to memory management, laziness, and so on, but it won't have the nice square-bracket **syntax** (at least in Haskell 2010; in modern GHC you can get the special syntax for your own types too, thanks to [overloaded lists](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_lists.html)).

---

As far as laziness goes, that's not special to lists, but is special to *data constructors*, or more precisely, *pattern matching* on data constructors. In Haskell, every computation is lazy. This means that whatever crazy chain of function calls you may construct, it's not evaluated right away. Doesn't matter if it's a list construction or some other function call. Nothing is evaluated right away.

But *when* is it evaluated then? The answer is in the spec: a value is evaluated when somebody tries to pattern match on it, and at that moment it's evaluated up to the data constructor being matched. So, for lists, this would be when you go `case myList of { [] -> "foo"; x:xs -> "bar" }` - that's when the call chain is evaluated up to the first data constructor, which is necessary in order to decide whether that constructor is `[]` or `(:)`, which is necessary for evaluating the `case` expression.

---

Index access is also not special, it works on the exact same principle: the implementation of the `(!!)` operator (check out [the source code](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.8/base-4.14.3.0/src/GHC-List.html#%21%21)) repeatedly (recursively) matches on the list until it discovers N `(:)` constructors in a row, at which point it stops matching and returns whatever was on the left of the last `(:)` constructor.

---

In the "simplest" lambda calculus, in the absence of data constructors or primitive types, I reckon your only choice is to Church-encode lists (e.g. as a fold, or directly as a catamorphism) or build them up from other structures (e.g. pairs), which are themselves Church-encoded. Lambda calculus, after all, only has functions and nothing else. Unless you mean something more specific.

Comment: You actually probably want one of the other encodings, maybe Scott encoding, so that you can cleanly mix it with the usual "`() -> a` is a thunk representing an `a`" trick.